# How do I pull text from a specific text line in Python?

Tags: python, editing, text-files

How would I pull text from a specific text line, inside a text file using Python?

Comment: How will you know which line you want to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read the 10th line:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for i in range(9):
        f.next()
    print f.readline()
```

This doesn't read the whole file in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The following Python example should extract the correct line number, but it is horribly inefficient:

```
f = open('file.txt')
print f.readlines()[line_number]
```

Comment: Are you saying this is inefficient, because you read in the file all at once?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method:

```
print list( open('filename') )[line_number]
```

That's gonna read in the whole file which may not be a good idea. A more efficient technique would depend on how you are using it.